# JavaScript and jQuery slider doesn't work in both directions

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slider

I have a bug in my slider code but I can't work out what it is... I can use either arrow to scroll the direction I want to however, if I scroll in one direction then scroll in the other without refreshing the page, the slider does not work correctly.

```
var box = $('.slider');
  var images = $('.images');
  images.addClass('hidden');
  images.eq(0).addClass('active');
  images.eq(0).removeClass('hidden');

  $("#arrow-right").click(function() {

    var image = box.find('.active');
console.log(image);
    images.removeClass('active');
    image.removeClass('zoomInLeft');
    image.addClass('zoomOutRight');
    if (image.index() + 1 == images.length) {
      var nextImage = images.eq(0);
    } else {
      nextImage = images.eq(image.index() + 1);
    }
    nextImage.removeClass('hidden');
    nextImage.addClass('active');
    nextImage.removeClass('zoomOutRight');
    nextImage.addClass('zoomInLeft');
  });

  $("#arrow-left").click(function() {

    var image = box.find('.active');
console.log(image);
    images.removeClass('active');
    image.removeClass('zoomInRight');
    image.addClass('zoomOutLeft');

    if (image.index() - 1 < 0) {
      var preImage = images.eq(2);
    } else {
      preImage = images.eq(image.index() - 1);
    }
    preImage.removeClass('hidden');
    preImage.addClass('active');
    preImage.removeClass('zoomOutLeft');
    preImage.addClass('zoomInRight');
  });
```

You can find a live version of the slider here: https://s.codepen.io/AdamHJacks/debug/bZaWKK#slider

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not accounting for the cases where the queued active image can end up with either zoomOut class, so a fix is to remove both zoomOut classes for the active element.

Make the following edits:

`nextImage.removeClass('zoomOutRight')` => `nextImage.removeClass('zoomOutLeft zoomOutRight')`

`preImage.removeClass('zoomOutLeft')` => `preImage.removeClass('zoomOutRight zoomOutLeft')`

Comment: Had to move my code around a little for it but now it works perfectly! Thank you very much!